# Baggage allowance inquiry with two different airlines in one ticket

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways, finnair

I am flying with two different airlines in one ticket. Finnair from Helsinki to Vienna and Qatar airways from Vienna to manila. Which airline baggage policy should I follow? There is no indicated baggage allowance in my electronic ticket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [United Airlines does not comply with baggage policy from IATA Resolution 302?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17748/united-airlines-does-not-comply-with-baggage-policy-from-iata-resolution-302)

Answer (score 8):

If a trip is purchased as a single ticket (as is the case here) then it is the baggage rules of *the most significant carrier* that apply.

In your case, since Finnair only handles a European flight and Qatar Airways handles an inter-continental flight, it would be Qatar Airways' baggage rules that apply to the entire trip.

If the flights were purchased separately, then the rules of each airline apply to each segment independently.